# Functions imported from another file can't call the variables from main file

Tags: python, python-3.x

here's my main.py

```
text = "hello"

def print_text() :

    print(text)

print_text()
```

it gives the desired output hello , now i want to split my code into two files like this

main.py

```
import functions

text = "hello"

functions.print_text()
```

functions.py

```
def print_text() :

    print(text)
```

It gives an error as - NameError: name 'text' is not defined

**Please Note that if possible i would like to call the variable from main.py not defining it on functions.py .**

*Thanks in advance and sorry if i did something on explaining my issue*

Comment: Why do you not want to pass `text` to the function as an argument?  Like this `print_text(text)`

Comment: as the i only give demo this isn't my real code there are lots of variables on def on real code , i don't want to mention them all

Comment: Yeah, that’s simply not how it works. What you’re describing is [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope_2), which Python doesn’t do.

Comment: okay i understand thanks for giving time

Comment: Is `text` a constant over the life of your program or a variable?

Answer (score 3):

functions.py

```
def print_text(text) :      <-- this is the change

    print(text)
```

main.py

```
import functions

text = "hello"

functions.print_text(text)   <-- change here.
```

So now you have defined the variable in main.py and still able to call functions method.